# ngModel does not update value on change

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel

I have ngModel, inside ngFor loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments">
   <div *ngFor="let answer of toArray(comment.answers); let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex;">
      <textarea id="editAnswer[j]" name="editAnswer[j]" [(ngModel)]="answer.text">

      {{ answer.text }}
   </div>
</div>
```

In my component i have two functions for index iterate and convert object to array:

```
  trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }

  toArray(answers: object) {
    return Object.keys(answers).map(key => ({
      key,
      ...answers[key]
    }))
  }
```

But when i change text what was binded in textarea, ngModel does not change.

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6xatv

Comment: try with this HTML <div *ngFor="let answer of toArray(comment.answers); let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex;">
   <textarea id="editAnswer[j]" name="editAnswer[j]" [(ngModel)]="answer.text">

</textarea>
</div>

Comment: You're tracking by `index`, that is the reason why `ngFor` isn't re-rendering `text`, you could try changing to `return index + obj.text;`

Comment: @PankajParkar does not work.

Comment: what is `comment.answers` in your method call ?

Comment: @PardeepJain this is the object that I get in the ngFor loop, i update my code in question.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem here ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbyo7w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Have you imported the FormsModule inside the app.module.ts imports section?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes, here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6xatv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toArray` method appears to be creating a copy of the original `comments.answers.text` values. When the `text` property is modified in the input elements, the change does not affect the original data (the console in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbqbl) shows that the values are not shared).

If you simplify `toArray` so that it returns a simple array of the `answers`, the code works (see [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnw8op)). The items in the array share the same `text` references as the original data.

```
comments = [
  {
    text: 'dsddsdsd', answers: {
      FszW: { text: 'answer 1' },
      dsSce: { text: 'answer 2' }
    }
  }
]

toArray(answers: object) {
  return Object.keys(answers).map(key => answers[key]);
}
```

---

If you need an access to the key, you can use this version of `toArray`:

```
toArray(answers: object) {
  return Object.keys(answers).map(key => {
    return { key: key, value: answers[key] };
  });
}
```

with the following template markup:

```
<textarea name="answer_{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="answer.value.text"></textarea>
{{ answer.key }}: {{ answer.value.text }}
```

---

As a side note, I suggest setting the name property in the template with one of the following syntaxes:

```
name="answer_{{j}}"
[name]="'answer_' + j"
```

Comment: but if I also need to get the item key?

Comment: I updated the answer and [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnw8op) with an example that includes the key in the array.